# Invoking anonymous function associated with an event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, anonymous-function

The following code does not work:

```
<input id="inp" type="text"
onfocus="(function(){document.getElementById('inp').style.background="yellow";})">
```

But this code works as I wish it to work:

```
<input id="inp" type="text"
onfocus="(function(e){document.getElementById('inp').style.background ='yellow';}(this)">
```

Why doesn't the first code work?

Comment: Inline event handlers are bad practice partially for this reason. The quotes become ambiguous between the HTML attribute and string literals.

Comment: Hint: look at the difference in syntax highlighting around `"yellow"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first doesn't work because it is wrapped in parenthesis and therefore it is a function "expression", rather than a function "declaration". Expressions are meant to be "evaluated", so when your element gets the focus, the expression is evaluated, but not invoked.  Also, you have double-quotes nested within double-quotes, which would cause a syntax error (`"yellow"`). Those would need to be changed to single quotes.

The second works because the "expression" is immediately invoked by the second set of parenthesis `(this)`.

However, both syntaxes should be avoided. Don't use inline HTML event attributes to wire up event handling callback functions because they:

- create spaghetti code that is hard to read and leads to duplication
  of code
- create global wrapper functions that alter the `this` binding in the
  function
- don't follow the [W3C DOM Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) standard

Instead, write your event handlers in JavaScript:

```js
// Get a reference to the DOM element
var input = document.getElementById("inp");

// Wire up an event handler
input.addEventListener("focus", function(e){
  input.style.background ='yellow';
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

First one have is not working because of:
IIFE syntax is like `(function(){}())` and `"` around yellow is pre closing the onfocus.

Corrected syntax is this.

`<input id="inp" type="text"
onfocus="(function(){document.getElementById('inp').style.background='yellow';})()">`

Comment: The first one doesn't use IIFE syntax at all, and also the placement of the IIFE part can be inside or outside the main expression.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't invoking the first function. Essentially, you're declaring a function but never calling it.

Example:

```js
(function() {
  console.log('I would do something but no one calls me');
}); // <-- Notice the lack of ()

(function() {
  console.log('I do something because I am called');
})(); // <-- Notice the () on the end
```

You also have trouble in the first example due to your use of double quotes (`"`) in the function. Since the `onfocus` attribute value must be wrapped in double quotes, you're prematurely closing that attribute.

```
<input onfocus="console.log("I won't work since I'm closing the quotes");" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott already answered your question very well. I'd just like to add to your second example:

```
<input id="inp" type="text"
onfocus="(function(e){document.getElementById('inp').style.background ='yellow';}(this)">
```

Should be:

```
<input id="inp" type="text" onfocus="(function(that) {that.style.background='yellow'})(this);">
```

There is no need to use the document.getElemetnsById method as you have already passed "this" element to the self invoking function.

But like Scott already mentioned you should use DOM Event Standard, handling evetns via HTLM attributes is old school.

Comment: Actually, you will need document.getElementById.... because 'this' won't be bound correctly with inline HTML event handling attributes. 'this' will wind up binding to 'window'.

Comment: That's incorrect Scott, in this case the method's owner is the HTMLElement object because the referrence to the method is in the HTMLElement's.onlclik property. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html article explains what is happening. If you enter my code snippet into jfiddle you'll see it works fine.

Comment: The only reason your code works is because you are passing 'this' into the function and receiving it as 'that'. Within the function, 'this' is bound to window. Instead of jumping through this hoop and for all the reasons I've listed above, don't use inline HTML event attributes in the first place.

Comment: It's important to understand that the scope of the code in `onclick` is the HTMLElement, but the provided callback is actually wrapped in a globally scoped anonymous function and the provided callback will execute within that scope (global). Since `this` is not inside the callbaack, it doesn't get wapped. That is why your code works.